# Metro framework form and controls text looks very small in design

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, metroframework

I downloaded the metro framework from nuget manager package to visual studio 2017.

The problem is that in the design view of the metro form, the control's text size (buttons, combobox, ...) looks very small.

You can look at the picture below to see the difference in text size between a regular button and a metro button.

[image: metro framework]

Please can you help?

Comment: @ThomasSmyth I did , is it fine ?
and please did you look at the pic ?

Comment: Link to the nuget package, or its API/documentation. There are multiple "metro frameworks".